# How do I deal with messages stating a file "Contained a virus and was deleted" in IE9?

Tags: anti-virus, virus, internet-explorer-9, spyware, anti-spyware

While doing Windows Recovery I installed IE9 on my Windows Vista machine.

This is the message I got when trying to download IE9 executable (or any .exe file) from IE9:

> IE9-WindowsVista-x86-enc-exe contained a virus and was deleted.

This is ridiculous!

It does not seem to be anti-virus software which is doing this.
I also turned off the smart filter and firewalls.

How do we solve this?

Comment: How can you be sure you haven't actually got a virus?

Comment: Hate to say it, but you may have an infection.  IE9 has no built-in antivirus.  It does have some anti-malware features, but they don't behave like this.  On the other hand, I have seen a lot of viruses do exactly this. Try downloading hijackthis (http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis) on another computer onto a flash drive, start the affected computer in safe mode, run hijackthis on it.  Don't do anything yet, just save the log file onto the flash drive, and add that to this post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Comment: **Where** did you get the notice? Was it *in* the browser (ie, a page) or was it outside of the browser? (I don’t mean a popup browser window, but rather a separate, non-browser system window; this is easier to detect with themes.) Try posting a screenshot if you get it again.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a typical ruse from one of the many rogue SpyWare-removal/anti-virus programs that people seem to keep getting infected with.  You should use these programs to scan your system, preferably from a clean system (with your suspect system's hard drive connected as a secondary drive so that whatever SpyWare or virus infected it will be dormant during the scan):

Malware Bytes
  http://www.malwarebytes.org/

SpyBot - Search & Destroy
  http://security.kolla.de/

F-Prot Anti-Virus (free 30-day trial, then $29/year for 5 computers)
  http://www.f-prot.com/

I use those three programs a lot.  They seem to do the job very well for my needs and have been instrumental in removing junk from other peoples' computers.

Comment: Also "purchase" yourself a copy of Symantec Endpoint Protection. It's not the best at removing malware after-the-fact, but I found that having SEP installed more or less prevents infection.

Comment: @todda.speot.is:  That won't be useful if the virus author designed their malicious code to circumvent that product.  In fact, this is true of all such products.  The most effective protection I've seen is with a product called DeepFreeze ( http://www.faronics.com/deepfreeze/ ) which returns everything back to its previous boot environment (particularly useful at schools and on public access computers), but the same caveat applies -- if a virus is designed to circumvent a particular security product, then that safety net is only an illusion (until an updated version can counteract/prevent it).